# What the briefest way to compose functions with early returns?

Tags: c++

I often use the following pattern composing functions that write to parameters given by reference and the other ones that take the same parameter as a constant.

For example:

```cpp
bool App::Initialize()
{
    Config config;           
    if (!ReadConfig(config))  
        return false;          
    if (!ApplyConfig(config)) 
        return false;          
}
```

Where the signatures of the methods are:

```cpp
 bool ReadConfig(Config& config); 
 bool ApplyConfig(const Config& config);
```

The approach above requires mentioning `config`, `if` and `return` multiple times.
Is there a briefer form of making such type of "chain" calls in c++?

Something like this in pseudocode:

```
bool App::Initialize()
{
  return build<Configs>().get(&App::ReadConfig).use(&App::ApplyConfig);
}
```

Comment: Clearly `ReadConfig` and `ApplyConfig` are doing some sort of validation (given the return value). Why not have them throw exceptions?

Comment: I wouldn't waste much time worrying about it. The compiler is likely to optimize either form of your function to much the same code. Similar to worrying about micro-optimization -- best to write clear and readable code and let the compiler do its job optimizing. Whether you use two `if` statements or a compound command with `&&` between them will make no difference in the end. Worry about profiling after your code is complete -- then you can concentrate on where actual significant savings can be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if that's all that function does, you could always take advantage of short circuit evaluation of logical operators:

```
bool App::Initialize()
{
    Config config;
    return ReadConfig(config) && ApplyConfig(config);
}
```